# nginx "root /parent/child " inside location directive not working and shows "404 Not found"

Tags: nginx

Im learning nginx and referring to book "nginx essential-valery kholodkov" for settingup nginx 1.8 and Im using centos 7 (selinux is off).

i made some changes to documentroot(like in apache 2.x) default configuration and when i add a location /images  like below

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
root /var/www/html/example.com;
index  index.html index.htm;
}
location /images {
root /disk2/images;
}
```

On browser when i browse to example.com/images/pen.jpg  i get 404 not found error.
but when i use **alias** it will work and pen.jpg is displayed.
below is configuration (location part) that worked

```
location /images {
alias /disk2/images;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here [multiple roots on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570321/configure-nginx-with-multiple-locations-with-different-root-folders-on-subdomain) answered by Shafiul karim

The **Location** directive system is like you want to forward all request which start **/static** and your data present in **/var/www/static**
so the configuration below worked!

```
location /images {
root /disk2;
}
```